# How to create trigger for insert UTC date&time automatically while insert record.?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, triggers, utc

I have mysql trigger for specific table, which insert date&time record while inserting any new record in table automatically. For this I used `NOW()` mysql function which return current system date and time. But in my requirement, need to store date and time in UTC format. For this I applied `UTC_TIMESTSAMP()`, but still it insert current system time.

following is my trigger.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `PawPhrazerProduct`.`caregiver_info_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `caregiver_info` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF NEW.createdDateAndTime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN SET NEW.createdDateAndTime = utc_timestamp(); END IF; END
```

Following are the column structure.

```
Column Name : createdDateAndTime

Data Types : TIMESTAMP Not Null Default '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: use convert_tz(now(),<your server timezone>,'UTC');

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka , I'm gone try this one.

Comment: please try and let me now

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka Sure will let you know.

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka it's working fine.